# Regex to ignore double quote while splitting records using any delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to modify a regex expression because its failing for a specific scenario.

`REGEX EXP - ~(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)`

After browsing some sites, I understood that this regex will simply separate records using *~* delimiter & check for 0 or even number of double quotes.

But if my input string is this:
`String str = "31-03-2021~QSTFONLN~QSAUSSUPER~1.00~A~BONNETT\"S SADDLERY PTY. LTD.~QVIF";`
The above regex is not working as expected.

**Expected result:**

> 31-03-2021

> QSTFONLN

> QSAUSSUPER

> 1.00

> A

> BONNETT"S SADDLERY PTY. LTD.

> QVIF

**Actual Result**

> 31-03-2021~QSTFONLN~QSAUSSUPER~1.00~A~BONNETT"S SADDLERY PTY. LTD.

> QVIF

Please explain this expression and the change required to get the expected result if the value has double quote as part of the string.
This question may be a duplicate of others but I want to retain the logic behind the original regex & modify the same expression so that it allows double quote in between the string.

Would appreciate any help on this.!

**Edited this post to include exact syntax of the input string**

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just search for the `~` and replace them with a carriage return?

Comment: I am modifying an existing code & I am skeptical because major changes could impact the current functionality. I need to understand the currently used regex exp and then make changes to handle the mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what the regex does. It splits on on all `~` characters unless it's in between quotes. But your input doesent have a quoted value, there is only a single `"`. Therefore the unexpected result. To show you an example input which makes sense:

```
String input = "foo~bar~baz~\"do~not~split~this\"~somemorestuff~999";
```

the `do~not~split~this` should stay together after spliting. And the provided regex is for such a string and produces:

```
[foo, bar, baz, "do~not~split~this", somemorestuff, 999]
```

It splits on on all `~` characters unless it's in between quotes.

Either you are missing a `"` in your input or that is not the regex you need. Looking at your expected output if the input is valid just do str.split("~")

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I have missed the exact syntax which has created confusion..my input string is getting stored in a string variable only..and as per ur answer I understand that it's taking the first quote and considering data as a single value till the 2nd qoute.. Double quotes in between the string value is causing issues.. probably this regex was used in the first place to allow users to use delimiters within data for CSV or other values..just using str.split will not allow users to use delimiters within same record.

Comment: Not sure if I get it right, but `str.split("~")` gives me the expected out put for your sample input `[31-03-2021, QSTFONLN, QSAUSSUPER, 1.00, A, BONNETT"S SADDLERY PTY. LTD., QVIF]`

Answer (score 0):

I personally love to test using [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test this stuff out.

The key distinction is **repeating a captured group** instead of **capturing a repeated group**. As you have already found out, the difference is that repeating a captured group captures only the last iteration. Capturing a repeated group captures all iterations.

Realistically, you probably want change your match to something simpler, like the following - `((?:[\w-]+)+)~?`.  This will do repeated matching on all word characters and dashes, but not the tilde and will capture a group capture.